# Error al leer de un fichero Excel(*.xlxs,*.xls)

Tags: c++

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en C++ Builder en el IDE RAD Studio 10.3. Quiero leer los datos desde un fichero Excel(xlxs,xls). A continuación le muestro mi código:

```
Variant vExcel,vFileName,vWorkbooks,vWorkbook,vWorksheets;
try{ vExcel = Variant::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");}
catch(...){vExcel = Variant::CreateObject("Excel.Application");}

vExcel.OlePropertySet("Visible",false);
vFileName = Edit1->Text;
vWorkbooks = vExcel.OlePropertyGet("Workbooks");
vWorkbook = vWorkbooks.OleFunction("Open",vFileName);
vWorksheets = vWorkbook.OlePropertyGet("Worksheets");
.
.
.
.
```

en la línea

```
vWorkbook = vWorkbooks.OleFunction("Open",vFileName);
```

me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Exception class EOleSysError with message'Tipo de variable incorrecto'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto resolvió mi problema.

```
 String dir = EUbicacion->Text;
 WideString urlfile = curDir + L"";
 vWorkbook = vWorkbooks.OleFunction("Open",urlfile);
```